# how to add textboxes and more after i selected the files i want to upload?

Tags: php, dynamic, pdo, image-uploading

so i have this multiple file uploader and i was wondering if i can do some stuff like add some textboxes, show the images in some thumbnails and even check for size/extension before i upload the data.

the thing is for each file selected i have to add some data to the database and I don t know how to make each textbox to appear dynamically and add the data to the database

here is the php code:

```
//cod pentru upload
if(!empty($_FILES['files']['name'][0])) {

$files = $_FILES['files'];

$uploaded = array();
$failed = array();

$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');


$i = 1;
foreach($files['name'] as $position => $fileName) {

    $fileTmpLoc = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
    $fileSize = $files['size'][$position];
    $fileErrorMsg = $files['error'][$position];
    $fileType = $files['type'][$position];

    $file_ext = explode('.', $fileName);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {

        if($fileErrorMsg === 0) {

            if($fileSize <= 4000000) {

                //fac query care sa mi salveze in variabila auto_incrementu

                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'history' AND TABLE_NAME = 'stories'");
                $stmt->execute();
                $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $auto_inc = $row['AUTO_INCREMENT'];
                $auto_inc--;

                 // end fac query care sa mi salveze in variabila auto_incrementul

                $fileName_new = $auto_inc . "_" . $i . "." . $file_ext;
                $file_destination = '../licenta/app/uploads/media/' . $fileName_new;

                if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $file_destination)) {
                    $uploaded[$position] = $file_destination;
                    //cod resize
                    include_once("ak_php_img_lib_1.0.php");
                    $target_file ='../licenta/app/uploads/media/' . $fileName_new;
                    $resized_file = '../licenta/app/uploads/media/thumbnails/' . $fileName_new;
                    $wmax = 200;
                    $hmax = 300;
                    //test
                     $white=imagecolorallocate($fileName_new, 255, 255, 255); 
                    imagefill($fileName_new,0,0,$white);
                    //end test
                    ak_img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $fileExt);
                    //end cod resize
                    //cod pic data to database
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO photos (file, notes, story_id) VALUES (:files, :notes, :story_id)";
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

                    $stmt->bindParam(':file', $fileName_new);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':notes', $_POST['descriere_poza']);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':story_id', $auto_inc);


                    if($stmt->execute()){
                        $message = "POVESTEA A FOST ADAUGATA";
                    } else {
                        $message = "EROARE";
                    }
                    //end cod pic data to database
                } else {
                    $failed[$position] = "[{$fileName}] failed to upload";
                }


            } else {
                $failed[$position] = "[{$fileName}] is too large";
            }

        } else {
             $failed[$position] = "[{$fileName}] failed to upload {$fileErrorMsg}";
        }

    $i++;   
    } else {
        $failed[$position] = "[{$fileName}] file extension '{$file_ext} not allowed.";
    }
}

if(!empty($uploaded)) {
    //cod in care ii zic ce sa faca cu ce s a uploadat cu succes
    print_r($uploaded);
}

 if(!empty($failed)) {
    //cod in care ii zic ce sa faca cu ce nu s a uploadat cu succes
     print_r($failed);
}


}
```

html code:

```
<form action="upload_test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <textarea name="descriere_poza" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="descriere" required></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>

    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
<p><?= $message ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this code is highly risky. do **NOT** pull an auto_inc value from the DB like that. if you have parallel uploads occuring, you WILL have 2+ scripts pulling out the same value and create a conflict. always insert a skeleton record, use last_insert_id() to get its id, then fill out the information properly. and note that you're simply assuming uploads will always succeed. There's an `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason. It should be the FIRST thing you check, because if the upload failed, everything else for that entry in $_FILES shouldn't be used or trusted.

Comment: what is a skeleton record? what if i move the code that gets the auto inc value outside the foreach loop? the think i m curious how i can do is make a instance of the story description textbox for each selected photo and before making the textboxes check if files are jpeg/png

Comment: you insert just the bare minimum necessary to create a record, just to get its id, then you do the rest of the processing. if the processing succeeds, you can complete the record and commit, otherwise you roll back and boom... nice clean work area